# Implementing a spinner on selection

Tags: java, wicket

I have a component that shows some text based on data retrieved from an API

```
public SomePanel( String id, IModel<Person> personModel)
{
  tallLabel = new Label( "height", new LoadableDetachableModel() {
    pubic String getObject() {
      Person person = personModel.getObject();
      boolean isTall = apiCallToCheckIfTall( person );
  
      return isTall ? "Tall" : "Short";
    }
  });

  add(tallLabel);
}
```

I have a spinner overlay component (separate markup & class, e.g. `SpinnerPanel`) that is supposed to show while the api is retrieving the data and disappear when complete. How would I implement this?

I've looked into `IAjaxIndicatorAware` but I'm not sure this is the right approach as it's supposed to refer to something in the markup for `SomePanel`. Additionally, if this is the correct approach, how would I link the state of the api call to the state of the spinner?

Could someone point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You'd use an AjaxLazyLoadPanel for that - plenty of answers to find, e.g.

[Wicket: Lazy loading DropDownChoice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17741964/wicket-lazy-loading-dropdownchoice)